# How to proof the mid-point theorem without triangle congruence theorems?

Tags: alternative-proof, congruences-geometry

Is there a way for me to proof the  mid-point theorem without using the triangle congruence theorems?

I can't seem to find one that's not using the triangle congruence theorems. The reason I'm trying to find the mid-point theorem without using the triangle congruence theorems is because, I'm reading about the proof for the triangle congruence theorem (specifically SAS) and they use the mid-point theorem to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vectors.

For triangle ABC let $\vec {AB}=p$ and let $\vec {AC}=b$.

Let midpoint of AB be M and let midpoint of AC be N.

Then $\vec {AM}=\frac p 2$ and $\vec {AN}=\frac q 2$

$\vec {BC}=\vec {AC}-\vec{AB}=q-p$

$\vec {MN}=\vec {AN}-\vec{AM}=\frac q 2-\frac p 2=\frac 1 2 (q-p)=\frac 1 2 \vec {BC}$

Thus MN is parallel to BC and half the magnitude.

Comment: I understand how you get MN is half of BC, but how do you determine that they're parallel?

Comment: If one vector is a multiple of another then they are parallel.